# XMLHttpRequest Error Refreshing Access Token from Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, adal

We followed [this](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet) project and wired up our MVC application to use the new ADAL bit but we are seeing the following error when the token expires:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.windows.net/0bccafdb-3696-4344-3269-991d0a93be57/oauth2/autho…QzLTk5MWUtOGE5KRLTIFMYWE3MTliNjU1YMJTLENi00YWIzLTllNDQtYmVmZWU4ZWFjMjQ1. The request was redirected to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%…ZAEkNmNhNzFiYTUtZWZhOS00YjE0LWExYTYtZjQ5NjgwMzU5NzEz7Q2&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&id=', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Related: [CORS preflight request responds with 302 redirect in Azure hosted Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097648/cors-preflight-request-responds-with-302-redirect-in-azure-hosted-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

That sample is not meant to be used with XMLHttpRequest. It is secured via a redirect based protocol, which in turn requires full browser postbacks for performing authentication operations. That protocol is not designed to work with Web API and AJAX calls, and although it can work for testing purposes production use will force you into hacks and other bad tactical measures.
If you want to make calls from JavaScript, please consider http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/.

Comment: Vittorio, can we do role-based authorization using  https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet approach ?

Comment: Only if you retrieve roles via graph api... The implicit flow won't include them in the token as it would become too big